# In the last few days I have slept "a very little"

Tags: quantifiers

Is it fine to use in "**a very little**" in such context?

> In the last few days I have slept **a very little**.

Normally, in such context I use "a little bit" but I'm not sure if "a very little" is idiomatic, because I didn't hear people who use it. So I decided to check it out before I use it.

Comment: You don't use "a" with "very little", because *little* is not a noun. Technically, *bit* is a noun, so you use "a" with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the "a" - "I slept **very little**" is the idiomatic version of this.

Compare "I had **very little** sleep".

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question based on your notes to be focus on the topic that I asked about. By the way what about "I slept **little** yesterday" (without "**very**")? and what about "I slept little bit yesterday" (it was not clear to me in your answer)

Comment: That would be technically correct, but considered highly poetic/downright incorrect in conversation - you can definitely say "I had little sleep", but "I slept little" sounds very strange to me. 

"little bit" is always used with "a" - "I slept *a little bit*", "could I have *a little bit*", etc.

Comment: You can use it with the "a" but it slightly changes the meaning. For example, "I slept a little" emphasises the fact that you _did_ manage to get some sleep. But, "I slept [very] little" focusses on the fact that you _didn't_ sleep as much as you wanted/needed.

Comment: @JamesRandom - very true, I completely missed that you can put "a" there!

Comment: @JamesRandom "I slept a little" is OK, but the real meaning is "I slept a little (while)".

Comment: @user3169 Not at all - it's more "I had a small quantity of sleep", in much the same way as "I ate a little" means "I had a small quantity to eat" or "I drove a little" means "I did a small amount of driving".